# Infer Generic Type-Arguments from a dictionary in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I need to create an object containing different methods.
Each method can have a different Payload.
Therefore I want to add type safety.

**Question**

Is there a way to specify that each method can have a different payload type?

**State as is**

The action is typed like the following:

```
export type Action<TPayload> = (payload?: TPayload) => TPayload;
```

Then I need to create a Dictionary of these methods.
The following code sample introduces the *error*.

```
export interface Actions<TPayload> { 
                      // ^--- TypeScript should get to know that TPayload is different for each action
  [key: string]: Action<TPayload>;
}
```

The following snippet shows that these typings lead into losing all information of the created dictionary.

```
class Customer {}
class Product {}

const actions: Actions<Customer|Product> = {
  addCustomer: (payload: Customer) => ({}),
  addProduct: (payload: Product) => ({}),
};
```

The object of `actions` does not have any method.

**My goal**

I want to get something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any feedback or suggestions on this.

**Background**

I want to preserve this typing information since I want to use a generic factory function later on that transforms that kind of method dictionary.

Comment: If you let TS infer `actions` by removing the type declaration (`: Actions<Customer|Product>`), it'll give you type safety on `actions` within that context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I have something different in mind.
But maybe I have to rephrase my question to be more specific.

Thank you for your Feedback.

Comment: Yeah, you might want to give some more background information. Maybe what you're looking for are [Index types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)